# Why does Netbeans Ant compile with correct jar but builds with old jar?

Tags: java, ant, build, jar, netbeans-7

I have a project "A" that has another project "B"  in it's libraries.
Netbeans compiles project "A" and says there are no errors but when I go to clean and build project "A" goes to an old version of project "B".
I have cleaned and built project "B" and then cleaned and build project "A" but "A" still fails thinking it is using the old "B".
I am trying to figure out why Netbeans' Ant is compiling with the correct Project "B"-dist/jar but is building with the old Project "B" jar.
None of the other jars in "A"s library have "B" in their library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found to solve this problem was to right click the library folder in netbeans and go to properties.  There was several projects and jars listed in red and that were not displayed in navigation I removed those then figured out which of those jars/projects I needed and added them back to project "A"s library.

Answer (score 0):

The class-path specified in your `build.xml` is separate from the project class-path in Netbeans. Apparently the latter is correct and the former is wrong. You can fix it by editing your `build.xml`.